# Exclude the release branchs from triggering with Jenkins stash-pullrequest-builder

Tags: jenkins

Trying to exclude the release branches from triggering with Jenkins stash-pullrequest-builder for pull request builds

**Build PR targeting only these branches:** Comma separated list of branch names (or regexes), blank for all branches.

I added the regex [^relesae/.*] at `Build PR targeting only these branches` to build prs with other target branches except release branches.

But builds are not triggering with any branches unless specify them at `Build PR targeting only these branches`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your regex, you are not excluing the release branch, you are only targeting the release branch. Try a negative lookbehind instead ( `?>!` ) :

```
(?>!^release)\/.*
```

This regex will **match** every branch that **doesn't** starts with "release".

You can test more branch name [here](https://regex101.com/r/GdU0ai/1).

**Note** I have not test this regex in a jenkins environment. It might not work as expected.